# Method to validate a JSON with an Array

Tags: javascript, postman

I'm doing some regression testing using Postman and I have the following function on the Pre-request Script tab:

```
postman.setGlobalVariable("verifyResponseChildValueMatchesExact", (children, key, value) => {
    pm.test(`A node with these parents '${children}' in the response should contain this key / value pair '${key}: ${value}'`, function() {
        const targetJson = eval(globals.getResponseChild)(children);
        if (!targetJson) throw new EvalError(`Node with parents '${children}' does not exist.`);
        pm.expect(Object.keys(targetJson)).to.include(key);
        pm.expect(targetJson[key]).to.eql(value);
    });
});
```

I call this using:

```
eval.globals.verifyResponseChildValueMatchesExact(["my_key"], "my_value", my_number)
```

the response to be validated is:

```
{
    "data": {
        "my_key": 42
    }
}
```

What I need is a function that follows that structure but capable of validating the key and the value in any position of the array

```
{
    "data": [
        {
            "my_key": 42
        }
    ]
}
```

and if possible (in the same function)

```
{
    "data": [
        {
            "my_key": 42,
            "my_key2": {
                "my_key3": "value"
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

e.g.: data, in position 0 has a child named "my_key" and it's value is 42. That's what I need to validate

Comment: What _exactly_ do you want to validate?

Comment: @kabooya e.g.: data, in position 0 has a child named "my_key" and it's value is 42. That's what I need my function to validate

Comment: The data isn't valide JSON. You can use a linter to validate it. I see unbalanced braces, missing commas and missing quotes.

Comment: @jabaa Fixed, thanks

Answer (score 0):

You will need a function that recursively checks if the requirement is true.

```
// Function to recursively search for key-value pair in nested objects
function findKeyValuePair(obj, targetKey, targetValue) {
    for (const prop in obj) {
        if (obj.hasOwnProperty(prop)) {
            if (prop === targetKey && obj[prop] === targetValue) {
                return true;
            } else if (typeof obj[prop] === 'object') {
                if (findKeyValuePair(obj[prop], targetKey, targetValue)) {
                    return true;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return false;
}

const keyValuePairExists = findKeyValuePair(targetJson, key, value);
```